# adding new language and phrase macros in Freeswitch

Tags: xml, freeswitch, ivr

I am trying to add some custom phrase macros in freeswitch.

1- First creating \ur folder under lang directory and adding it in `freeswitch.xml`

```
<!-- languages section (under development still) -->
<section name="languages" description="Language Management">
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="include" data="lang/ur/*.xml"/>
...
```

2- creating `\ur\ur.xml` file that includes language configuration.
3- creating a lang\ur\urdu\phrases.xml [code as follows]
4- adding sound files under `sounds\ur\ivr`
5- reloadxml

Files:

**ur.xml** `\lang\ur\ur.xml`

```
<include>
 <language name="ur" sound-path="$${sounds_dir}/ur" tts-engine="" tts-voice="">
  <phrases>
   <macros>
     <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="include" data="urdu/phrases.xml"/>
   </macros>
  </phrases>
 </language>
</include>
```

**phrases.xml** `\lang\ur\urdu\phrases.xml`

```
<include>
<macro name="greet_urdu_main_menu" pause="100">
    <input pattern="(.*)">
        <match>
            <!-- Play Urdu Main Menu Welcome File -->
            <action 
            function="play-file" 
            data="ivr/urdu-welcome.wav"/>
        </match>
    </input>
</macro>
</include>
```

**Freeswitch console message:**

`unable to find macro "greet_urdu_main_menu"`

It works perfectly when I add it under `en` macros. Somehow, `ur` language configurations is not being loaded correctly. Please provide some pointers to debug this issue.